# git branch created from windows not seen on gitbash window

Tags: windows, git

I created a new branch from my windows command box from the devdesktop application. but when I got to git bash and try to find this branch it doesn't exist.  What can I do to sync what I see in git bash with what I created?

Comment: you sure you were looking at the same .git repository ? do you see the branch if you `git branch --list` ?

Comment: Actually, you should see the branches. There is no need to sync branches between multiple interfaces. Are you sure you are in the same directory/repository? Can you run `ls .git/refs/heads` and give the output? Your branch should be in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was in another repository which had the same directory structure but was on a separate drive.

Answer (score 0):

Choose one of below commands:

(1) Display latest branch with timestamp:

```
git for-each-ref --sort='-authordate:iso8601' --format=' %(authordate:relative)%09%(refname:short)' refs/heads
```

(2) List all branches at remote and local:

```
git branch
```

(3) List all branches, order by commit time desc, you will see lasted touched branch:

```
git branch --sort=-committerdate
```

(If order in ASC, `git branch --sort=committerdate`)